# Trigger file-input explorer when element is selected in dropdown

Tags: jquery, image, file, meteor, explorer

How do I trigger input file when the value `UploadStudents` is selected from the dropdown?

select element

```
<select name="performaction" id="performaction">
  <option value="">- Actions -</option>
  <option value="UploadStudents">Upload Students</option>
</select>
```

File input

```
<input type=file name="uploadlogo" id="uploadlogo" style="visibility:hidden"/>
```

Comment: This becomes really hacky. You may rather use the select to show/hide another form (targeted by the option's value via Id) which implements the upload. Way easier to implement and to maintain. When the subforms grow to big, you can easily extract them into own templates.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the Template.Name.js file, you need to trigger a `change` event on the `select` tag.

```
Template.Name.events({
    'change #performaction' : function(event, template){
        event.preventDefault();
        $('input[type=file]').click();
    }
});
```

And if selection specific implementation, then you can use as below;

```
Template.Name.events({
    'change #performaction' : function(event, template){
        event.preventDefault();
        var selection = event.target.value;
        if(selection == "uploadStudents"){
            // your specific input file trigger like 
            // $('input[type=file]').click();
        }

    }
});
```